# kernel_require.rb:15:in `require': cannot load such file -- 3.0/pg_ext (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require': cannot load such file -- 3.0/pg_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `rescue in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:176:in `require'
        from D:/Onl_course/Ruby/David_Battersby/instagram-clone/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
```

Comment: my gemfile:source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.3"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.1"
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem 'pg'
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"
gem 'devise'
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "turbo-rails"
gem "stimulus-rails"

Comment: gem "jbuilder"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]
gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem "sassc-rails"
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.1.3'
group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end
group :development do
  gem "web-console"
end
group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, on Unix there is a misleading error of "File does not exist" when loading a shared module, when dependencies of such a shared module don't exist. It may also be a case here.

An obvious dependency that's missing is Postgresql client libraries. You should install Postgresql to attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: i have already installed Postgresql ( version : 10.19 ) but still not work

Comment: Have you tried restarting your system afterwards? This may help to ensure that your environment variables are set correctly

Comment: Anyway still, for Ruby development on Windows I would highly recommend using WSL. It's well integrated with Windows (and especially utilities like VSCode) and Linux is the primary Ruby environment.

Comment: this proect, i just created "rails new " and add gem 'pg' in gemfile but when started it's alert that errors and i don't know why when i add gem 'pg' and always alert that errors ( i already add portgres and check in cmd )

Comment: It may be that your Postgresql installer didn't adjust the PATH. You may need to do something like ``` PATH="C:\Program Files\Postgresql\Bin;%PATH%" your_ruby_command ``` (of course you will need to adjust the path to the location where the Postgresql DLLs are located).

Comment: This DLL should be called something like libpq.dll or pq.dll. You may as well try to copy it into your C:\Windows\System32 directory to solve the issue... even if that's not the best way to proceed with that.

Comment: i already added but new errors : connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: thanks you! i have already fixed that errors !